# PhoneGap:Develop on one platform and deploying to all.Is it possible?

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-7, mobile, cordova

Today i wrote a simple PhoneGap app on Eclipse.And I became interested, is it posible to write one App on Java and all other platform versions to by generated automaticly,or for every platform I  must create dev enviromnent and create a separate app .

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

[PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/) takes the files you include in the WWW folder in a PhoneGap project and then builds apps for multiple paltforms so you don't need to have a build environment for each platform you wish to target. [iOS is a special case though](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/ios-builds).